# A problem on lebesgue integration

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f$ is integrable on $(-\pi,\pi]$ and extend to $\Bbb R$ by making it periodic of period $2\pi$. I need to show that

$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx = \int_{I} f(x) dx$$.

where $I$ is any interval in $\Bbb R$ of length $2\pi$.

I have a solution of this using change of variable formula. But, the excercise is present in a first chapter of a book where the material is till the dominated convergence theorem. I guess there might be some other solution.